# R and ggplot2: create summary statistics for overlapping ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of records characterized by multiple variables, marked as either "in" or "out". I want to plot summary statistics for all records together and for those marked "in", while plotting each point only once, colored to show which ones are "in" or "out". How can I do that? I only know how to plot the summary statistics for the "in" and "out" groups (see code below), not for "in" and "all". 
It would be a plus if the legend explained the colors for the points (as in my illustration) as well as the colors for the error bars.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
d = data.table(v1 = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
              v2 = rnorm(10, 1, 2),
              g = as.factor(c(rep('in', 7), rep('out', 3))))
m = melt(d, c('g'))
print(ggplot(m, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = g)) +
      facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free") +
      geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.2)) +
      stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.25))
```

[image: Plot with summary statistics for "in" and "out"]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "plot summary statistics?" What does the final plot you want look like?

Comment: By summary statistics, I meant the functionality provided by "stat_summary" (see example code). The final plot looks like the one I provided, except that you would have "in" and "all" instead of "in" and "out" ("all" referring to all rows, "out" referring to those for which g is "out").

Comment: Your code gives 'Error: could not find function "melt"'. This is because, although `melt` is in data.table, you need to load package reshape2 as well (according to "? melt").

Comment: It didn't give an error on my machine. It seems you are using an older version of data.table. This is what the help of my version says: "From 1.9.6, to melt or cast data.tables, it is not necessary to load ‘reshape2’ anymore. If you have to, then load ‘reshape2’ package before loading ‘data.table’."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show in and out points, but errorbars for in and total, you should move your colour command and add different stat_summary for in and all:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2) #needed because data.table::melt will only work with reshape2
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.table(v1 = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
               v2 = rnorm(10, 1, 2),
               g = as.factor(c(rep('in', 7), rep('out', 3))))

m <- melt(d, c('g'))

ggplot(m, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + # removed colour here
        facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free") +
        geom_jitter(aes(colour = g), position = position_jitter(height = 0, width = 0.2)) + #added color here
        stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.25) + #errorbars for total observations
        stat_summary(data=m[m$g == "in",], fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.25, colour = 2) # errorbars for "in" group
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping with this! Yes, this works - except that you now have two points for the rows that are labeled "in".

Comment: @jciloa maybe something wrong with the data copying. I will look into it later, am a bit busy right now...

Comment: I think the data copying is correct. Only this approach requires the "in" points to be present in "all", which is useful for plotting the summary statistics, but these points will be plotted two times (and will usually be seen two times, due to the added jitter).

Comment: @jciloa Aha, I think I get it now: you want to show the in and out points, but the errorbars for in and all. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear; I am going to edit my question. Yes, this is what I want. Thanks! (I now just need to add a legend to explain what each errorbar color means. If you happen to know, I'd appreciate that, too.)

Comment: @jciloa I think on hindsight your question is clear. I've edited my answer to only show the right solution. For a legends, that is not really straightforward, but I think there are solutions to be found on SO.